# TregexPattern with Stanford parser

Tags: regex, parsing, nlp

I want to extract two verb in this sentence.

> > Be assured that and send me.

Tree looks like this.

```
    (ROOT
       (S
          (VP
              (VP (VB Be)
                  (VP (VBN assured)
                      (NP (DT that))))
              (CC and)
              (VP (VB send)
                  (NP (PRP me))))
                      (. .)))
```

How can I extract VB using TregexPattern..
There is some confusing problems.
1. first VP has no contents. so whenever sentence include "and, or" I have to ignore empty VP node.

2. Be.   I want to extract assured. not Be.
3. send.  I have to find "send" using "Be", they have same dependency. but Be is not that I want.

   ```
       TregexPattern noNP = TregexPattern.compile("((@VP=verb > (S !> SBAR)) !$,,@NP)");
   ```

this is my code for extracting No-subject verb.
how can I extract thoes two verb.

https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/tregex/TregexPattern.html

here is detail about patterns.